# how to prevent wordpress to upload photos with the variety dimensions?

Tags: wordpress, fotorama

I am using wordpress plugin fotorama. (see: http://fotorama.io)
My all prictures have same dimension 800px of height. But when I use fotorama I see that some of pictures  have named something like :

DalyPhotos-020-1024x627.jpg

and not using the original picture which is named like this:

DalyPhotos-020.jpg

Naturally when I see the slideshow every picture have a different height. How can I prevent  wordpress uploading photos with different dimension like: DalyPhotos-074-300x224.jpg or DalyPhotos-074-300x200-1024x550.jpg 
If it is not possible how can I force fotorama to use same dimension.

Comment: Predefined image size are used in your theme, you should take a look at add_image_size function here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_image_insert_override($sizes){
    unset( $sizes['thumbnail']);
    unset( $sizes['medium']);
    unset( $sizes['large']);
}
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', 'add_image_insert_override' );
```

Or just go to Settings -> Media and set all the sizes to 0.